# What could make jOOQ stop mapping columns on my POJO

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have been using jOOQ successfully for a couple of months now, using @Column annotations to provide jOOQ with column mappings on my POJOs.

Then, after a code merge last week, a couple of the mappings stopped working. Obviously I have been through a lot of Diffs to try and find what has changed in the code to cause the change in behaviour, but to no avail.

For example, I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.address
    (
        address_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('address_address_id_seq'::regclass),
        address_line_1 character varying(255) NOT NULL,
        address_line_2 character varying(255),
        address_line_3 character varying(255),
        town_city character varying(255),
        postcode character varying(20),
        country_id integer NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (address_id),
        CONSTRAINT fk_address_country_id FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
            REFERENCES public.country (country_id) MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )
```

and this annotated POJO:

```java
@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
private String addressId;
@Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE_1")
private String addressLine_1;
@Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE_2")
private String addressLine_2;
@Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE_3")
private String addressLine_3;
@Column(name="TOWN_CITY")
private String townCity;
@Column(name="POSTCODE")
private String postcode;
@Column(name="COUNTRY_ID")
private String countryId;

public String getAddressLine_1() {
    return addressLine_1;
}

public void setAddressLine_1(String addressLine_1) {
    this.addressLine_1 = addressLine_1;
}

public String getAddressLine_2() {
    return addressLine_2;
}

public void setAddressLine_2(String addressLine_2) {
    this.addressLine_2 = addressLine_2;
}

public String getAddressLine_3() {
    return addressLine_3;
}

public void setAddressLine_3(String addressLine_3) {
    this.addressLine_3 = addressLine_3;
}

public String getTownCity() {
    return townCity;
}

public void setTownCity(String townCity) {
    this.townCity = townCity;
}

public String getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}

public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
    this.postcode = postcode;
}

public String getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}

public void setAddressId(String addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}

public String getCountryId() {
    return countryId;
}

public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
    this.countryId = countryId;
}
```

To make jOOQ map the values from the DB on to the POJO I have had to rename the address fields on the POJO from adressLine1, addressLine2 and addressLine3 to addressLine_1, addressLine_2 and addressLine_3.

To be clear they were working without the underscores in field and accessor names before "the merge".
I have also found, by working on other classes that have developed the same problem, that the naming of the accessor functions does not matter. Just the names of the fields.

So I would like to know if there is some configuration that would cause this change in behaviour or have I made some error on my mappings may be?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you mind rewriting your prose to actual code? E.g. your DB table would be easier to digest if you showed the *exact* `CREATE TABLE` statement that defines it. The same is true for `MyClass`. From experience, I just suspect that some relevant problem (e.g. unmatching case sensitivity) might have gotten lost from translating your code to prose.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what your question really is. You show a bit of code, but then refer to things like `start_date` (which aren't in your code), or `blaa_blaa_` (which I also don't see). It's really hard to answer such a question without spending 30 minutes thinking about what you might have meant. Please, can you rewrite your question completely, reducing it to the *minimum* that is necessary to understand your problem. Here's a guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when at the end of the column name there is underscore and number (e.g. _1, _2), field names will contain underscore. To fix this, edit your pom.xml:

```
<generator>
    ...
    <strategy>
        <matchers>
            <fields>
                <field>
                    <expression>^(.*?)_(.\d*)$</expression>
                    <fieldGetter>
                        <transform>CAMEL</transform>
                        <expression>get_$1$2</expression>
                    </fieldGetter>
                    <fieldSetter>
                        <transform>CAMEL</transform>
                        <expression>set_$1$2</expression>
                    </fieldSetter>
                    <fieldMember>
                        <transform>CAMEL</transform>
                        <expression>$1$2</expression>
                    </fieldMember>
                </field>
            </fields>
        </matchers>
    </strategy>
</generator>
```

first expression tag contains field names which will be taken into account: the ones ending with underscore and digit. The other expression tags will construct a string made from prefix (for getter get_, for setter set_, for field members none) and from the strings on both sides of underscore ($1 and 2$). Later strings are transformed to camel case, which removes all underscores and treats them as word separators.

So, for example, your address_line_1 setter will look like:
set_address_line1 after applying expressions, and setAddressLine1 after transformation.